# change height of bootstrap breadcrumb dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap breadcrumb and I was trying to change its height dynamically using either javascript or jquery but neither are working. Searching around SO I found that I should set `!important` but that didn't work either. How can I change the height of the bootstrap breadcrumb? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  const currentDirectoryHeight = $('.currentDirectory').height()
  console.log(currentDirectoryHeight) //prints height of bread crumb
  //expected change height of breadcrumb
  $('.currentDirectory').attr('style', 'height: 200% !important');
}, 3000)
```

```css
.infoBar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 5%;
  width: 90%;
  height: 25%;
  background-color: green;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 5px 15px;
}

.infoBar .currentDirectory {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  min-width: 60%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="infoBar" id="infoBar">
  <nav class="currentDirectory" id="currentDirectory" aria-label="breadcrumb">
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
      <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Library</a></li>
      <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Data</li>
    </ol>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: The `#currentDirectory` element _does_ get a height of 200px here. But that doesn't change the height of `.breadcrumb` automatically ... You could add `height: 100%` to that.

Comment: @CBroe That doesn't fix it too. Check update did that.

Comment: or you can apply your height change to `.breadcrumb` instead: `$('.breadcrumb').attr('style', 'height: 200px');`

Comment: @tromgy tried that didn't work

Comment: You made the height for `#currentDirectory` a percentage now (which doesn't have any effect, since it has no parent with a specified height.) I was talking about `.breadcrumb`

Comment: its parents (```.infoBar```) has a specified height. And if you meant apply it to ```.breadcrumb``` it tried that too didn't work.

Comment: @seriously, how do you want it to look like? Here's an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-kate-jte2l?file=/index.html) with the `.breadcrumbs` change. Did you want to achieve something else?

Comment: @tromgy thats right how can you center the items in the middle ```.breadcrumbs{
    text-align:center;
    line-height:50px;
}```?

Comment: @CBroe I thought you were referring to the whole breadcrumbs class didn't see the ```.``` tromogy's answer explained it